# how to use files that are inside a ftp server to make a table with ftplib.. All with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, server, ftp

I have to make a program that generates a table, from data extracted from files generated in a ftp server, these files are generated daily in the directory of the server ftp, therefore the table would have to be generated daily.
Everything has to be done with python
Does anyone have any ideas?
Sorry, I tried with this program:

```
import ftplib

# Connection information
server = 'ftp0.micasa.es'
username = 'anonymous'
password = '---------'

# Directory and matching information
directory = '/expl/publico/MI_HABITACION/'
filematch = '*.txt'

# Establish the connection
ftp = ftplib.FTP(server)
ftp.login(username, password)

# Change to the proper directory
ftp.cwd(directory)

# Loop through matching files and download each one individually
for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
    fhandle = open(filename, 'wb')
    print ('Getting ' + filename)
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write)
    fhandle.close()
```

the program runs and does not give errors, but it does not print anything on the screen or show the files anywhere.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that What are the columns the table should have? And more important, what have you tried so far and where did you encounter problems?

Comment: I have not been more specific because I do not know how to do it. Hence my question.
At first I thought about starting downloading the files in txt and then selecting rows and columns, but I had many problems since the table is filled in at different UTC times.

Comment: Can it be done in Python? Certainly yes. How? First download files from the ftp server with the `ftplib` module, then parse them and build your table. I cannot say more if you do not show would you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have been trying to download all the files from an ftp0 server but it does not show me anything and it gives me an error. How can i donwload all files on a direction in the server?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of some web development frameworks like Flask/Django. You can also use them to store data in the database and also display them as tables in the HTML page.

Comment: Sorry, i have to extract the files from a ftp server. No from a web directory

Comment: This tries to be an answer... unfortunately it does not address **this** question...